# Why is this JSON not valid?

Tags: json

JSONLint is giving me an error of "Expecting 'EOF'" at the comma that separates the "blah"s.  I'm stumped.

```
{
    "blah": false,
    "heynow": [
        {
            "Name": "one",
            "Duration": 2,
            "DurationUnit": "Hours"
        },
        {
            "Name": "two",
            "Duration": 40,
            "DurationUnit": "Minutes"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "blah": true,
    "heynow": [
        {
            "Name": "three",
            "Duration": 2,
            "DurationUnit": "Hours"
        },
        {
            "Name": "four",
            "Duration": 40,
            "DurationUnit": "Minutes"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two JSON objects need to be wrapped in something. I suggest an array. For example:

```
[
    {
         "blah": false,
// ...
    },
    {
         "blah": true,
//...
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an array with two objects. In that case, the array is represented with enclosing `[]` in JSON.